# how to allow to execute all store procedure at linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have many link servers and each database have a lot of store procedures.
So it will take a lot of time to set one by one.
Could someone show me a way to allow all store procedures to be executed on linked server?
P/s: I'm using sql 2008 R2

Comment: What do you mean allow them to be executed?

Comment: grant permission to let store procedure to be used at linked server.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the linked server and everything to do with the user you are using to connect. Thus, grant that user executable privlages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable `RPC OUT` on your linked server.

You can do it using GUI (Linked Server Properties) or by using the following code:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MYSERVER', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
```

More on this here: [What is the RPC and RPC Out option on a SQL Server linked-server?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jason_howell/2014/10/01/what-is-the-rpc-and-rpc-out-option-on-a-sql-server-linked-server/)

Comment: Thank for your help.